# FadeOut div that is inside the div containing the button to hide it

Tags: jquery

So, i have a DIV called "item" and inside it I have a button to show more contents ("description"). Inside this new (now showing) "description" div I have a button to hide "description" again.

Take a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6ou9va87/1/

html

```
<div class="item">
<span>click me</span>

<div class="description"><span>hello</span>
<div class="close-item-description"><span>close</span></div>
</div>

</div>
```

jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".item").click(function(){
                $(".description").fadeIn();
                $(".close-item-description").click(function(){
                    $(".description").fadeOut();
                });
            });
        });
```

css

```
.description{

  display: none;
}
```

The problem is that i can't hide the div after it shows up. It should be working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your close button click raises show click again, to stop it u should use stopPropagation

https://jsfiddle.net/6ou9va87/2/

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".item").click(function(){
            $(".description").fadeIn();
            $(".close-item-description").click(function(e){
                e.stopPropagation();
                $(".description").fadeOut();
            });
        });

    });
```